# While Loop, Strings

Tags: java, while-loop

I am new to java programming language. I've been practicing the `while` loop statement with `String`s and I can't seem to get this code right. I've been getting error:

> variable choose might not have been initialized

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String args []) {
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

 int a, b,c, diff, prod, q, choice;
 String name;
 String choose;


 System.out.print("Enter Name Please:       \t");
 name = sc.next();

 System.out.println("WELCOME  " + name);
 System.out.println("");

while (choose == "Y");
{
 System.out.println("1. Addition  \t2. Subtraction \t3. Multiplication \t4. Division");
 System.out.println("Please Choose a number: \t");
 choice = sc.nextInt();

 switch (choice)
 {
   case 1:
       System.out.println("Thank You "+name+", you have chosen ADDITION");
       System.out.print("\nPlease Enter the first number: \t");
       a = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.print("\nPlease Enter the Second number: \t");
       b = sc.nextInt();

       c = a + b;

       System.out.println("\nYou have chosen "+a+ " as your first number, we will add it to "+b+" your second number.");
       System.out.println("\nThe answer is "+c);

       System.out.println("\nWould you like to choose again? Y/N: \t");
       choose = sc.next();

       break;
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: You might want to consider using a `do-while` loop instead, as you don't care about the `choice` until AFTER the user has entered it...

Comment: `do...while` would still require that `choice` be initialized.  I don't disagree, though.

Answer (score 2):

You use the variable `choose` before you set it to an initial value. You don't ever assign `choose` any value before you use it in the `while` loop.

Add this statement before the `while` loop:

```
choose = sc.next();
```

Of course, you'll want an appropriate message for the end user.

Also, your comparison is incorrect - use `choose.equals("Y")` or `choose.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")`, since you [don't compare objects with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

[EDIT]:  Looking back at your code, your `while` loop would be busted anyway. Remove the semicolon from the end of it.  This way, it will enter the loop when you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a safety net built into the compiler and it's complaining that String choose may not have been declared before it is used in your while statement. Declare it to "" and you'll be good to go.

```
String choose = "";
```

Hope this helps! Welcome to Java!

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign any value to variable `choose`.

Answer (score 0):

change `String choose;` to `String choose = "";` this will initialize the String choose.

Answer (score 0):

The variable *choose* is not being initialized to a value, and is just being declared. Maybe you want *String choose = "Y";*? Maybe you wanted another user input with *Scanner* after entering the name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize **choose** ,that is, **assign a value to it while declaring it**. Maybe you could do this - `String choose = "Y"`. And as others have mentioned, using `equalsIgnoreCase("Y")` would be better.